# Storing password along with encrypted file

Tags: encryption, password-management

I was making a small application to encrypt files and ran into the problem of verifying that the provided key is the correct one when decrypting. My idea was to store the (padded, encrypted) key along with the encrypted file so when you want to decrypt, the program first checks if the first couple of bytes (un-padded) equals the provided key. I'm no security expert and I can't see a problem with the approach but i still have a feeling that this would be a bad practice some how.

Is this approach OK from a security perspective? Is there perhaps already another solution to the initial problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While there's no obvious vulnerability here, a better option is simply to store a static string, rather than the key itself. If an attacker finds a side-channel attack which allows them to discover one block of plaintext, your approach would leak the passphrase and thus break the whole system, whereas the fixed text option would not.

Comment: FWIW, this is the method that TrueCrypt uses.

Comment: Not sure about static. In the movie The Imitation Game they said that the German crypting had been broken because of static prefixes to some encrypted messages, and we don't know what kind of cypher OP wants to use. Maybe prefix equal to random x and some f(x) would be better.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko This is only the case with weak cryptosystems, such as Enigma, which are vulnerable to known-plaintext attacks. Modern ciphers (e.g. AES, DES) are heavily resistant to known-plaintext attacks.

Comment: I agree, but the OP didn't mention AES nor DES. Maybe he xors the file with the key, the question was posed rather abstractly.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko In which case the cryptosystem would be screwed *regardless* of the use of either scheme, so the choice is redundant at that point.

Comment: I do not fully agree. If I stored my passwords, which I had uniformly randomly generated, in binary structure xored with some master password, I don't think it would be possible to crack the file. Unless of course I put some constant substring there. Anyway, I just mentioned that your advice is not universal, that's all.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Such a scheme would be breakable once the password dictionary exceeded a certain size, simply by finding key bytes which produce valid binary structures containing only ASCII strings. Each key byte could be independently discovered to be part of a small known set, producing (in aggregate) only a few hundred or thousand possible master passwords. If the master password has any structure, the true password could be deduced from that. If not, candidates could be compared against any captured offline hash.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Additionally, one would expect that your passwords would have usernames or service names associated with them, within the database, and thus deducing known-plaintext would be trivial.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Just to validate my thoughts, I wrote some code which generated 10,000 random password databases, each containing 30 passwords of length between 20 and 40 characters (random), using a dictionary of a-z, A-Z, 0-9, plus 29 ASCII symbols. Each list item is delimited by a null, though with no trailing null. These databases were encrypted using a repeating-xor of a 22-character password (mixed case, numerics and symbols). In 3 cases I could recover the password definitively. The best case was a keyspace of size 409,227,831,936,000 - still one 3x10^28th of the password's keyspace.

Comment: What about padding to a specific block size? Most ciphers need padding anyways and padding errors are easily recognizable.

Comment: @JonasKöritz What are you referring to? The hypothetical repeated-xor system? Or OP's system? If it's the repeated xor, that makes breaking it trivial: the padding would require some known padding structure which would reveal the key bytes directly.

Comment: Trying to decrypt data with incorrect padding would raise errors, why should he store the key at all?

Comment: @JonasKöritz Oh, you're talking about OP's scheme. The problem there is that you introduce a padding oracle vulnerability if you do it wrong.

Comment: He seems to be doing his own crypt, this would be doing it wrong already.

Answer (score 10):

You could do this:

1. Generate cryptographically secure random 128-byte key
2. Generate hash of random key
3. Encrypt the file with the random generated key
4. Encrypt the random key with the user provided key
5. Put the following values in the file:

   **encrypted random key:random key hash:encrypted file data**

When want to decrypt the data, you use the user provided data to decrypt the encrypted random key, then you hash it and compare with the stored hash. If they are the same, you use the now decrypted random key to decrypt the data.

Comment: "hash:encrypted file data" shouldn’t that be "hash: random key"?

Comment: @idmean I understood it as `encrypt(random key, user key) + ':' + hash(random key) + ':' + encrypt(data, random key)`, where ':' is just some delimiter.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues Of course, now I see. I read that as kind of key-value-pairs.

Answer (score 3):

Including a static string sounds as if it could be vulnerable to a known plaintext attack. Instead I'd to the following (but would be pleased to hear if it's a bad idea!);

1. Hash your plaintext and prepend the hash to it
2. Encrypt everything with your encryption technique

When you decrypt it, check if the hash at the beginning matches the hash you expect. This makes you able to detect if you got the correct decryption key and as a plus you get integrity checking for free. If you want to speed this up, say you'd like to encrypt large amounts of data where it is not feasible to run a hashing function over the entire payload, reduce the hashed portion to a few megabytes or blocks if it is a block cypher.

If you'd add an unecrypted hash of the key itself to the file, attackers may test keys without having to decrypt the whole file. This would speed up attacks a lot.

Comment: What you are describing i essentially an authenticated encryption. I think authenticated encryption is the right tool for the task. But I am not sure the method you describe will actually produce a secure authenticated encryption. I have certainly come across recommendations to use designs where the data is authenticated before you start decrypting.